# React Native with WebView versus Cordova

Tags: cordova, react-native, phonegap

I cannot locate any useful breakdowns on the key differences, pros/cons, etc. of shipping a cross-platform application based on web technologies. I need some native capabilities but curious on why developers would use Cordova over React Native when both offer WebView capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova apps are built entirely *within* a WebView.

React Native translates your JSX UI templates into native widgets -- one of which is WebView, if you really want it. RN is only really "web technology" in that it uses JS.

The app that you get when you compile a React Native project has a fully native UI, controlled across a JSON bridge by your JS code, which runs in a VM. Cordova, on the other hand, essentially just provides a Chromium instance for your HTML and JS to run in. Performance is almost guaranteed to be far better with RN than with any WebView-based wrapper.

Comment: Also, FWIW, writing custom native modules for RN is extremely straightforward